# Add an extension location entry in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5

I look in my menu entry for :

> add an extension location

[image]

but I do not find I'm using Eclipse Galileo
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The concept of extension locations was dropped by p2, the new update-manager since Eclipse 3.4 (or 3.3?), for a detailed discussion about this descision see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224145 and see how you you can share your bundles through multiple Eclipse instances at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Bundle_pooling